# Akka remoting: Remote subscribed event listener custom serialising a Watch message

Tags: scala, akka, remoting

I have the following remote actor set up.

```
actorSystem.actorSelection(remoteConfig.getString("/myEventListener")).resolveOne().map{ar =>
    actorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(ar, classOf[MyEvent])
  }
```

I also have my own custom serialization.  The issue is that this gets sent a Watch message which has the following signature:

```
private[akka] final case class Watch(watchee: InternalActorRef, watcher: InternalActorRef) extends SystemMessage
```

Which is not so straight forward to serialize.  Any suggestions on how to proceed on this one?  Sending a remote message with references to InternalActorRef seems a bit of an odd one.

And to note I use other remote actors directly (not as event listeners), these dont get sent the Watch message:

```
val emailService = actorSystem.actorSelection(remoteConfig.getString("/emailCommandHandler"))
```

Comment: instead of `InternalActorRef`s you could go for `ActorPath`. you can create actor ref using ActorPath anytime

Comment: Im not sure I follow. Is this for the Watch.  I'm not generating that message, just trying to de/serialize it. Should I serialise it into something else then?

Comment: `private[akka] final case class Watch(watchee: ActorPath, watcher: ActorPath) extends SystemMessage`.. here `ActorPath` is more sensible then `ActorRef`.   or `private[akka] final case class Watch(watcheePath: String, watcherPath: String)`

Comment: I mean to say ... Serialize into String which is Actor Path.

Comment: OK, I think I follow (maybe not though). But then deserialisation gets a bit tricky as I would need to create an instance of the private[akka] Watch class. And wouldnt the internalActorRefs be pointing to locallised actors, which the remote server wont have?

Comment: IP address can be sent in the message itself or it can be read from the config. now IP address and actor path will uniquely identify the actor.